# Change VBA Coding to allow command to happen if certain cells contain any data

Tags: excel, vba, text, copy, row

I need help figuring out the right verbiage for the VBA Coding that I have in my excel workbook.
Currently I have the entire row copying to another sheet when pressing a button if a specific cell contains the word "Fail". I am wanting to change that to the next cell over on the pages to move the entire row if containing any words no matter whether the previous cell says "Pass" or "Fail".

Here is what my coding is so far:

```
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Fail" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher").Activate
        
    End If
```

So I need it to change to `cell(i, 12)` instead of `cell(i, 10)` and I would like that stated cell now to be able to copy the row like I have it doing below if it contains any value, but not copy other rows that contain no data in `cell(i, 12)`.

Hopefully this makes sense as to what I'm looking to do.

So since posting I have found the solution in my VBA coding see below, but new problem has started. I want the VBA code to look at `cells(i, 12)` only after row 22 on the specified sheet. I've tried using "FirstRow22" but that makes it so the VBA code does nothing.

```
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a
    
    If Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(i, 12).Value > "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher").Activate
        
    End If
```

I feel like I may just be missing a line of code before this part:

`If Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(i, 12).Value > "" Then`

THIS ADDITION IS TO THE COMMENTS BELOW BY FANEDURU:

Here is the entire code now with your changes. I receive a 'Run-Time Error' depending on how many rows are being copied.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'unprotect sheet
Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Unprotect Password:="JODA"

a = Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 21 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher pg2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher pg2").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg2").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg2").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher pg3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher pg3").Cells(i, 12).Value = "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg3").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg3").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher pg4").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher pg4").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg4").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg4").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher pg5").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher pg5").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg5").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg5").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("Extinguisher pg 6").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Extinguisher pg 6").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg 6").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Extinguisher pg 6").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("E-Lights").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 21 To a

    If Worksheets("E-Lights").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("E-Lights").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("E-Lights").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("E Lights pg2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("E Lights pg2").Cells(i, 11).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("E Lights pg2").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("E Lights pg2").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("E-Lights pg3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("E-Lights pg3").Cells(i, 11).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("E-Lights pg3").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("E-Lights pg3").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("E Lights pg4").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("E Lights pg4").Cells(i, 11).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("E Lights pg4").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("E Lights pg4").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("E Lights pg5").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("E Lights pg5").Cells(i, 11).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("E Lights pg5").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("E Lights pg5").Activate
        
    End If
Next
a = Worksheets("E Lights pg6").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("E Lights pg6").Cells(i, 11).Value <> "" Then
        
        Worksheets("E Lights pg6").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("E Lights pg6").Activate
        
    End If
Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Range("A1:N300").Locked = True

'protect the sheet back
Worksheets("Repairs Sheet").Protect Password:="JODA"
    
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Again the run time error seems to change where it comes out at based on how many rows I am asking the coding to copy to the "Repair Sheet".

Comment: So, do you want iterating between 22 to the last cell (of A:A column) and copy the row if any value is found in column 12 (L:L). Is this understanding correct? If yes, do you need to also copy the row format? If not, I can show you a much faster way, able to deal with large ranges in seconds.

Comment: Please, do not post code in a comment. You have to edit your question and place there any clarification you need to make. Even a new code version.

Comment: Thank you FaneDuru. I have edited my question with the new coding. I don't think I want what your first comment was. I fixed the coding to do what I asked originally but on my sheet it's now copying information above that I don't want it to. When looking at the excel sheet I would like the VBA to begin to run at row 22

Comment: After re-reading your first comment, I don't really care if it copies the row format. I might be interested in a faster way, but I am running this code over 12 different sheets one at a time, so I don't know if that will make a difference for your suggestion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want, if my supposition is wrong. I would suggest 
 that line `If Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(i, 12).Value > "" Then` should be transformed in `If Worksheets("Extinguisher").Cells(i, 12).Value <> "" Then` (not equal with nothing) and starting iteration from row 22 is solved writing `For i = 22 To a`. But this reflects my initial supposition which has been considered as wrong...

Comment: Do you want copying from those 12 sheets in the same ("Repairs Sheet") sheet? Did you try the above suggestions? Otherwise, I cannot prepare any code able to help.

Comment: I don't mean to offend. But I'm not as versed in this coding as yourself. I will try what you've suggested as it makes more sense. So If I'm understanding correctly the part that states i = 2 or i = 22 refers to the row to begin at?

Comment: Yes they should be all pasting below the lasted pasted line one sheet at a time

Comment: Of course, yes. But when you do not understand something, it is better to ask for clarification, instead of saying that the supposition is wrong. I am not offended. I'm just puzzled...

Comment: So, did my suggestions solve your problem? If yes, should I prepare a piece of code copying from a sheets name list (the 12 you mentioned) and doing it faster then your code, without selecting anything?

Comment: Your answers helped tremendously. I'm not sure how to mark this as answered by FaneDuru

Comment: The screen keeps asking to move our conversation to a chat and I don't know how to do that. I will show you the entire coding in a chat and if you can make it simpler that would be great because at the end of the run I always get errors. But it does work now the way I want, but if no errors at the end that would be better.

Comment: No need to do it (theoretically, it is enough to press the link announcing it). I will prepare a piece of code in 3 - 4 minutes...

Comment: I get an error stating "Run-Time Error '1004'"

Comment: Do you want to see my entire coding?

Comment: What entire coding? Do you need something else then you show us? When you talk about an error, you must state **on which line it is raised**. Otherwise, we cannot understand what is happening.

Comment: Ahh - I will show all coding and where the issue is beginning by adding to my question above if you think that is best...

Comment: The error run time doesn't seem to be an issue, but sometimes it will stop code from continuing to run through all the rest of the sheets listed in code

Comment: Please, try the code I posted. I would suggest you to place in the sheets array only two or three sheets name, to test the code...

Comment: Take care to separate the sheets  name with only the comma ("," not ", ")...

Comment: I am trying the code now. I will reach back after I press the button and see what happens on the "repair sheet"

Comment: Please, do it in some minutes. It is enough to copy the code in a standard module and run it... In some minutes I will close my laptop. It is late in my country...

Comment: You can let the sheets name array as it is. It will return only data from the first (existing in your case) sheet name in the array... You will add the rest of the sheets name in later step.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Have a great evening.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. You should appropriately fill the string to make the sheets to be processed array (`arrSheets`):

```
Sub copyRowFromManySheets()
 Dim shE As Worksheet, shR As Worksheet, lastRE As Long, firstRE As Long, mtch
 Dim lastRR As Long, lastCol As Long, arrE, i As Long, rngCopy As Range, arrSheets
 
 arrSheets = Split("Extinguisher,SheetX,SheetY,SheetZ,SheetETC", ",") 'place here the names of your sheets to be processed

 Set shR = Worksheets("Repairs Sheet")
 firstRE = 22 'the row where the iteration must start
 
 For Each shE In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets                'iterate between all sheets
    mtch = Application.match(shE.Name, arrSheets, 0)  'find the iteration sheet in the sheets array
    If Not IsError(mtch) Then                         'if it exists in the array:
        lastRE = shE.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'calculate last row
        lastCol = shE.UsedRange.rows.count              'calculate last col
        
        arrE = shE.Range(shE.cells(firstRE, 1), shE.cells(lastRE, lastCol)).value 'place the range to be processed in an array (to wark faster)
                
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrE)                        'iterate between the array elements
           If arrE(i, 12) <> "" Then                     'if column 12 row value is not nothing
               If rngCopy Is Nothing Then                'if the range to be copied has not been Set
                   Set rngCopy = shE.Range(shE.cells(i, 1), shE.cells(i, lastCol))
               Else
                   Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, shE.Range(shE.cells(i, 1), shE.cells(i, lastCol))) 'make a union between the existing range and the new row
               End If
           End If
        Next i
        If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then                      'if the range to be copied is Set
            lastRR = shR.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'calculate the target last row
            'copy all the range at once (much faster then copying of each row) and make the variable Nothing
            rngCopy.Copy Destination:=shR.cells(lastRR + 1, 1): Set rngCopy = Nothing
        End If
    End If
 Next shE
End Sub
```

Comment: On this I'm noticing that the Row 22 seems to be placing the pasted rows onto row 22 on "Repair Sheet" I was most likely unclear as this is just slightly over my head being new to this. I meant I want the row on Sheet "Extinguisher" & "E Lights" to start being processed at Row 22. The other sheets "Extinguisher pg2", "E Lights pg 2", "Extinguisher pg3", etc. need to start being processed at row 2.

Comment: I want the iteration to begin on row 10 of the repairs sheet

Comment: The iteration in the sheets to be processed starts from row 22. You can make it whatever you need only changing `firstRE = 22` in `firstRE = 10`, or whatever you need. The code pastes in the last empty row of "Repairs Sheet". Now I am closing my laptop.

Comment: @Chassee Shobe The processed result will be dropped in the first empty row of **A:A** column. But if in the column A:A will also not be any values in the pasted rows, next time it will paste in the same previous cell. If the code still does not work as you need, if not something confidential, can you share your workbook? I will adapt the code according to your specific problems. You can send it on my personal mail (in my profile) or on a transfer site.